# How can i update the contents of a file by replacing strings using grep and find command

Tags: linux, grep, find

I am finding  XML files under particular sub directory having "responsible" word in it. Searching is working fine as shown below.

```
find . -name '*.xml' -exec grep -H 'responsible' {} \;

./dir1/d1.xml<responsible><></responsible>
./dir2/d2.xml<responsible><SYSTEM></responsible>
./dir3/d3.xml<responsible><SYSTEM></responsible>
```

... and so on.

Is there a way i can replace all occurrences of SYSTEM with blank one.

result i am looking is:

```
./dir1/d1.xml<responsible><></responsible>
./dir2/d2.xml<responsible><></responsible>
./dir3/d3.xml<responsible><></responsible>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use perl pie

```
perl -p -i -e 's/<responsible><SYSTEM><\/responsible>/<responsible><><\/responsible>/'   `find ./ -name *.xml`
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix.